# Decimal comaprison in Java script

Tags: asp.net, javascript, scripting

I am trying to compare two decimal values in Java script. I have two objects as  one assogned value "3" and the other as "3.00". When i say if (obj1 == obj2) it does not pass the condition as it is does the string comparision.

I would instead want it to do a decimal comparision where 3 = 3.00. Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm) describes how to convert a string to a floating-point number; I believe that is what you want. This would let you compare the numbers as numbers, which I think is what you mean by "decimally". Beware that doing an exact comparison between two floating-point numbers is often considered a bit "hazardous", since there are precision issues that might cause two numbers that you would consider "equal" to not compare as such. See, for instance, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which is a classic text on the topic. Perhaps a bit on the advanced side, but try searching for something more basic in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do type casting:

```
var a = "3.00";
var b = "3";

Number(a) == Number(b) // This will be true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(parseFloat(obj1) == parseFloat(obj2)) { // ...
```

But heed unwind's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try parseFloat() like this:

```
if(parseFloat(obj1) == parseFloat(obj2))
```

parseFloat() concerts Strings to float.

Answer (score 0):

As strings, they are not equal. As integers, they are, but your example implies float and this is a problem. Avoid equality comparisons of float numbers due to their nature: their precision is limited, and after miscellaneous arithmetic, you might end up comparing numbers like 1.0 and .99999999999 and getting "not equal".